# Is the SerialPort.Write method affected by context switches in case of multiple accesses by threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

as the title says I wonder if and how the [SerialPort.Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8) method may be affected by context switches if different threads attempt to write to the same shared serial port.

For example, lets say we have two threads A and B and A gets called before B in this example.
Thread A wants to do this at some point:

```
serialPort.Write("abcdef");
```

and thread B this:

```
serialPort.Write("123456");
```

What can happen to the output?
Will it be:

```
"abcdef123456"
```

or will it be mixed up somehow like this:

```
"a12bcd3e45f6"
```

If the first thing is the case, that's good. Otherwise I might need to prevent the context switch..

Comment: You will want to use manual synchronization here.

Comment: Will it matter for your use case whether your program will send "abcdef123456" or "123456abcdef"?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError so does this mean that the stream will be mixed up?

Comment: @elgonzo No that doesn't matter. It is just important that they don't get mixed up.

Comment: Potentially it can be, yes.

Comment: Okay, if it doesn't matter which thread sends first, then simple synchronization of access to the SerialPort object should do the trick...

Comment: Alright. I will do that. Thank you both!